# Bigquery SQL fails with Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

BigQuery fails on my query with the following error, and I'm not sure how to mitigate this.

> Query error: Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not
> supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming
> them into an efficient JOIN. at [31:1]

##### Standalone SQL Query (and temporary tables) to reproduce:

```
create temporary table records (
  ID int64,
  Events array<struct<
    Tag string,
    Info string,
    Citations array<struct<
      Tag string,
      SourceID int64>>>>);

insert into records values
(1, [
    ('A', 'C', [('AA', 1000), ('AB', 1001)]),
    ('A', 'C', [('AA', 1000), ('AB', 1001)]),
    ('B', 'D', [('BA', 1000), ('BB', 1001)])]);

create temporary table sources (
  ID int64,
  Title string);

insert into sources values
(1000, "ABCD"),
(1001, "EFGH");

select 
  Record.ID,
  array(
    select as struct
      Event.Tag,
      Event.Info,
      array(
        select as struct
          Citation.SourceID,
          Citation.Tag,
          Source.Title
        from unnest(Event.Citations) as Citation
        left join sources as Source on Citation.SourceID = Source.ID
      ) as Citations
    from unnest(Record.Events) as Event) as Events
from records as Record;
```

##### The `events` table looks like (in json):

```
[{
  "ID": "1",
  "Events": [{
    "Tag": "A",
    "Info": "C", 
    "Citations": [{
      "Tag": "AA",
      "SourceID": "1000"
    }, {
      "Tag": "AB",
      "SourceID": "1001"
    }]
  }, {
    "Tag": "A",
    "Info": "C", 
    "Citations": [{
      "Tag": "AA",
      "SourceID": "1000"
    }, {
      "Tag": "AB",
      "SourceID": "1001"
    }]
  }, {
    "Tag": "B",
    "Info": "D",
    "Citations": [{
      "Tag": "BA",
      "SourceID": "1000"
    }, {
      "Tag": "BB",
      "SourceID": "1001"
    }]
  }]
}]
```

##### The `sources` table looks like:

```
[{
  "ID": "1000",
  "Title": "ABCD"
}, {
  "ID": "1001",
  "Title": "EFGH"
}]
```

##### I'd like the output to look like:

```
[{
  "ID": "1",
  "Events": [{
    "Tag": "A",
    "Citations": [{
      "Tag": "AA",
      "SourceID": "1000",
      "Title": "ABCD"
    }, {
      "Tag": "AB",
      "SourceID": "1001",
      "Title": "EFGH"
    }]
  }, {
    "Tag": "B",
    "Citations": [{
      "Tag": "BA",
      "SourceID": "1000",
      "Title": "ABCD"
    }, {
      "Tag": "BB",
      "SourceID": "1001",
      "Title": "EFGH"
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below instead.

```sql
SELECT
  ID,
  ARRAY_AGG((SELECT AS STRUCT Event.* EXCEPT(Citations), Citations)) AS Events
FROM (
  SELECT
    r.ID,
    ANY_VALUE(e) Event, --> will discard *e.Citations* in outer query whatever it is
    ARRAY_AGG((SELECT AS STRUCT c.*, s.Title)) Citations
  FROM records r
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(r.events) e WITH offset
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(e.citations) c
  LEFT JOIN sources s ON s.ID = c.SourceID
  GROUP BY r.ID, offset
) GROUP BY ID;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Hi Jay. Thanks for looking into this. Two issues with this solution. __First:__ I've got extra columns in Events that i would want to maintain (I elided them to simplify, maybe I elided too much). With this, I would need to do a pretty gross `any_value(e.FieldA)`. __Secondly:__ I can't do `GROUP BY e.Tag`. There is no primary key inside that array. Potentially entire rows will appear twice (and should not be dropped)

Comment: I've updated the question to better reflect this. I added a field `Events.Info` to try and reflect this complication.

Comment: @BillLynch, would you check my updated answer again and correct me if I'm wrong with your explanation ?  I thought **First** part can be resolved with `ANY_VALUE`  you mentioned  and `SELECT AS STRUCT .. EXCEPT..`, and **Second** part with `WITH OFFSET` which can be used as a primary key with in an array.

Comment: I hate that this works, but it does. It's such a gross way to write it. Thanks for providing a method though!